# WebHost failed to process a request on IIS 7 windows 2008 when using Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, wcf, iis-7

I have developed a webservice using WCF and secured it using NTLM over SSL. I am able to connect successfully using from a visual Studio 2008 form or Web Project. The problem I am having is when creating a  smart device project and deploying it on the device.

when I call the service, from client side I get the error: Web Exception

on the server site, when i check the Event Log I get the following Error:

```
**Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/7491627
 Exception: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): There was no channel actively listening at 'https://mymachine:9011/FrontEndWS/MeterReadingService.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening. --->  
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'https://mymachine:9011/FrontEndWS/MeterReadingService.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening. 

at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)**

Process Name: w3wp
  Process ID: 2828
```

Cannot figure out why this is happening from mobile devices but works fine from a PC.